# Chrome ignores Nginx upstreams (loads only first)

Tags: google-chrome, nginx, load-balancing, proxypass

I have simple setup of 3 servers (in containers) - 2 "app" servers (whoami services - so by response I can acknowledge server) and nginx server.
I've launched nginx with simple load-balancing configuration:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    upstream myapp1 {
        server w1:8000 weight=1;
        server w2:8000 weight=1;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://myapp1/;
        }

    }
}
```

The problem is that it doesn't work in Chrome - it always loads only first server. I've tried to turn off cache in Dev console + reload via CTRL+F5 but nothing helped.
If I try to `curl` nginx server - I get responses in round robin manner (as expected).

Here is my containers setup:

```
docker network create testnw
docker run -dit --name w1 --network testnw jwilder/whoami # app1
docker run -dit --name w2 --network testnw jwilder/whoami # app2
docker run -dit --name ng --network testnw -p 8989:80 -v ${PWD}/my.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf nginx # LB server
curl localhost:8989 # will get response from w1
curl localhost:8989 # will get response from w2
curl localhost:8989 # will get response from w1
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit 3: Found out an interesting issue.
In chrome every time I access my website it makes two calls no matter what they are called to/of my website and /favicon.ico of my website.
I don't have a /favicon.ico.
What I think is happening

1. when Nginx is getting requests for/of my website, it is loading the first server upstream.
2. when chrome loads / from my website it also calls /favicon.ico of my website which results in making a new call to Nginx so it loads the .ico files from the next server upstream.
3. this happens so that servers 1,2,3 are loaded in order 1(ico file from 2),3(ico file from 1),2(ico file from 3). and cycle repeats.

once I stopped the loading of /favicon.ico in Nginx, my three upstreams servers 1,2,3 are loading in order 1,2,3 of round-robin.

I put this in the server with upstream to disable loading favicon.ico from Nginx.

```
location = /favicon.ico {
  log_not_found off;
}
```

Hope anyone having this problem find this useful.

Edit 2: Figured out the issue, the load balancing is working fine with static files and static servers inside the Nginx conf file.
but my applications are being loaded by node, so had to start Nginx after starting all the node servers.
Issue reappears when I restart the application server while Nginx is running.
Now no issue will update soon

Edit 1: This is not working for me anymore, this worked yesterday, today continued working on the same configuration, the issue reappeared.

Had this same issue with my setup.
What worked for me after a lot of proxy setup and VirtualBox setup and network editing.

Add an extra server block in the HTTP block.

```
server{
}
```

and reload the Nginx service.

It worked for me, after reloading once both chrome and firefox loads the servers in the given order, I deleted the server block and it is still working.

Don't know why the issue raised in the first place.
Hope this helps to solve your issue.